# Laravel 5.7 Import Excel File: Undefined offset

Tags: excel, database, laravel, import, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to import an excel file and save it into the database but I get the error and I don't know what this means, I'm new to Laravel though.

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   Undefined offset: 14

Here's my code for the Model:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Resident([
        'resident_fname' => $row[1],
        'resident_lname' => $row[2],
        'resident_mi'    => $row[3],
        'resident_dob'   => $row[4],
        'role'           => $row[5],
        'resident_age'   => $row[6],
        'resident_address'  => $row[7],
        'resident_contact'  => $row[8],
        'resident_email'    => $row[9],
        'resident_purok'    => $row[10],
        'resident_status'   => $row[11],
        'resident_gender'   => $row[12],
        'resident_religion' => $row[13],
        'ResidentVoter_status'  => $row[14],
    ]);
```

Here's my code for my controller:

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $import = Excel::import(new ResidentImport, request()->file('import_file'));
    dd($import);
    return view('pages.residents')->with('success', 'Imported Successfully');
}
```

this is the code for my File button:

```
<form action="{{ url('/import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></a>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="file" name="import_file" style="direction: rtl;"></input>
        <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button></form>
```

while here is my routes:

```
Route::post('/import', 'ImportController@import');
```

Can anyone help me with this? I really don't have any idea with what to do with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error menans that the row array does not have a 14th position. Arrays start at 0 so instead of 1 to 14 access 0 to 13 on the model.

Comment: It worked! but may I ask another thing? what does this mean? "Add [resident_fname] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Resident]."

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent Check the mass assignment section, Laravel models have a `fillable` attribute you have to set in order to perform some operations on them.

Comment: it worked! Thanks for the Help! It meant a lot! Have a great day ahead! :)

Answer (score 4):

Put @ before row variable. `@$row[14]` . It will ignore if row variable is undefined.